# Can't install anything from the terminal of software center in 15.04

Tags: apt, software-center, 15.04, dependencies

A while back I installed some software (I think it was some SDK software) and it didn't work so I removed it. Ever since I have been having problems with Ubuntu. That was back in 14.10 and I was hoping that updating to 15.04 would fix it, but it didn't help. Whenever I start up Ubuntu and log in, it tells me that a problem was detected and wants me to send a report. I eventually stopped sending reports because it was the same thing over and over again. Now I can't even install software from the terminal repos or from the software center. This is the error I get when the Software Center tries to fix it:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ...   
(Reading database ... 5%  
(Reading database ... 10%  
(Reading database ... 15%  
(Reading database ... 20%  
(Reading database ... 25%  
(Reading database ... 30%  
(Reading database ... 35%  
(Reading database ... 40%  
(Reading database ... 45%  
(Reading database ... 50%  
(Reading database ... 55%  
(Reading database ... 60%  
(Reading database ... 65%  
(Reading database ... 70%  
(Reading database ... 75%  
(Reading database ... 80%  
(Reading database ... 85%  
(Reading database ... 90%  
(Reading database ... 95%  
(Reading database ... 100%  
(Reading database ... 562833 files and directories currently installed.)  
Removing click (0.4.33) ...  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 31, in <module>  
    from click import commands  
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'  
dpkg: error processing package click (--remove):  
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 click  
Error in function:   
Setting up pay-service (2.0.0+14.10.20140916-0ubuntu1) ...  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 31, in <module>  
    from click import commands  
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'  
dpkg: error processing package pay-service (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
Setting up click-apparmor (0.3.8) ...  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 31, in <module>  
    from click import commands  
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'  
dpkg: error processing package click-apparmor (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-app-launch:  
 ubuntu-app-launch depends on click-apparmor; however:  
  Package click-apparmor is not configured yet.  

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-app-launch (--configure):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-app-launch-tools:  
 ubuntu-app-launch-tools depends on ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.4+15.04.20150410-0ubuntu1); however:  
  Package ubuntu-app-launch is not configured yet.  

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-app-launch-tools (--configure):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity8-private:amd64:  
 unity8-private:amd64 depends on pay-service; however:  
  Package pay-service is not configured yet.  

dpkg: error processing package unity8-private:amd64 (--configure):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

And this is what I get after using apt-get install:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 click : Depends: python3-click (= 0.4.33) but 0.4.38.5 is to be installed
 openvpn : Depends: libpkcs11-helper1 (>= 1.11) but it is not installable  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am sick of all the errors, and I have thought about reinstalling Ubuntu, but I don't want to start all over again getting it back the way I want it.

EDIT:
So apparently, the problem solved itself without me doing anything.
Thanks everyone for responding to me so quickly and giving me such good advice!

Comment: Maybe your sources are messed up. Try `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and add the output to your question. Leave out the `# comments`.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: Try this: `sudo mv /usr/bin/click /usr/bin/click.bak`. Update your system and install software and maybe `click` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/click` is a problem.

Make a backup

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/click /usr/bin/click.bak
```

or remove it

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/click
```

and update the repositories

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then I would suggest to delete `click` with

```
sudo apt-get remove click
```

Now, upgrade your system and install software.

For a better resolution of dependencies, I recommend `aptitude`.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

and use it like `apt-get`

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
sudo aptitude install <package_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) 2 problems:

1) You have package **click** installed but its removal depends on files that are missing. Try to force-remove it: `sudo apt-get -f remove click`

2) You have dodgy package **openvpn** that depends on the wrong packages. Try removing that too:  `sudo apt-get -f remove openvpn`

Then run `sudo apt-get check` and let us know if there are further errors.

Comment: **openvpn** is **NOT** dodgy. There is no reason to do that. instead try and figure out *why* the dependencies are not installable.

Comment: If you had even tried, you would have noticed that this is not working.